# vuetify 3 decimal number input

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

How can I have a decimal input in vuetify 3 that allows `.` as input so that I can write for example "123.45"?

My current code:

`MyNumberInput.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="value" type="number" :label="label" outlined />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  label: string;
  modelValue: number;
}>();

const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

const value = computed({
  get: (): number => props.modelValue,
  set: (value: number) => {
    // value is type string actually and when `.` is entered I get NaN
    emit("update:modelValue", value); // won't work as it returns the value which is of type string or NaN
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works for now

```
const value = computed({
  get: (): any => props.modelValue,
  set: (value: any) => {
    if (value !== "") {
      const float = parseFloat(value);
      if (!isNaN(float)) {
        emit("update:modelValue", float);
      }
    }
  },
});
```